# Neo4j A Star low performance

Tags: neo4j

I'm facing very low performance when I execute the A* algorithm provided by neo4j; I created a test project based on maven; you can find it here https://github.com/angeloimm/neo4jAstarTest

Basically these are my tests:

- A* from node 1 to node 2: 1416 millis
- A* from node 1 to node 300000: 3428 millis
- A* from node 1 to node 525440: 4128 millis

I was wondering if these times are the best time I can get or if I can improve them

In the configuration file you can see that I configured neo4j ith this settings:

- nodestore_mapped_memory_size=250M
- relationshipstore_mapped_memory_size=3G
- nodestore_propertystore_mapped_memory_size=250M
- strings_mapped_memory_size=500M
- arrays_mapped_memory_size=50
- cache_type=strong

The neo4j version is 2.0.3

Any tips would be really appreciate.

Thank you

Angelo

Comment: tried to download http://geodati.fmach.it/gfoss_geodata/osm/output_osm_regioni/lombardia.osm.bz2 file as discribed on your github project. However it's only 14 bytes. When unpacking it's 0 bytes - that gives pretty decent performance ;-)

Comment: well I never used the get full URL option; I always selected the region Lombardia, selected the file extension (.osm.bz2) and then downloaded it...and it's around 180 MB :)

Comment: does not work for me. If you can provide a download link being working, I could probably help you.

Comment: Sorry...I just saw that the last update of the site is around 14b for the extension .osm.bz2; I guess something was wrong....Please may you try with http://geodati.fmach.it/gfoss_geodata/osm/output_osm_srtm/lombardia_srtm.pbf ?

Comment: That seems to be a different format, the importer does not do anything. I guess it's more easy if you provide your graph.db directory on some download site.

Comment: Today it seems to be working again :) this is the link http://geodati.fmach.it/gfoss_geodata/osm/output_osm_regioni/lombardia.osm.bz2 and it's around 190 MB

Answer (score 0):

The reason for being slow here is that the two nodes in questions are not connected with each other, the end node is located in a distinct subgraph from the startnode.

Maybe consider a different strategy for that kind of scenario. Maybe in a first run, check in there are principally any paths between the two nodes and only if that is true, apply aStar to find the shortest one.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thank you for answering to me...I don't understand what you mean when you say that the end node is in a distinct subgraph. Moreover...may you explain better the strategy you proposed? Thank you

Comment: The start and end node based on your ids are not connected at all (at least in the DB I've built up), there is no path between them since "findSinglePath" returns `null`. Please note that node ids are might be different from your database to mine. It's better to do a lookup based on an indexed property to find start nodes for traversals.

Comment: Maybe we tested different IDs. By the way, in my tests the A* returns to me a path (singlePath returns a not null value) in the times I reported. I don't undertand how to use the indexed property for the start nodes finding....in my real scenario the start node is selected by an user by a web interface and I need to find the shortestpath

Comment: Assuming start and end nodes for your traversals refer to locations having a `name` property. In this case you'd first look up start/end node by `graphDatabaseService.findNodesByLabelAndProperty()` and pass this into the `PathFinder`.

Comment: I guess I got what you mean; but in my real scenario my intention is (or better...was since this performances) to use neo4j in order to create a routing system; I create the graph by reading the OSM file, then I have a web interface where user can select the start point and the end point (and if needed I have to create ghost points) and then I have to present to the user the found paths so I guess I can't think about labels and so on; in this case it seems to me that neo4j doesn't have the performance needed for a production environment or I'm missing something.....

Comment: in this case you could use Neo4j Spatial to geo-index the locations by its longitude and latitude and find the nearest location by a index lookup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54429/discussion-between-angelo-immediata-and-stefan-armbruster).

Comment: Hi Stefan; I tried to test also Dijkstra and shortestPath; times are better than AStar..above all shortest path (but it's normal since, as far as I know, shortestPath is bidirectional, while Dijkstra and AStar not yet)